# Toshiba Satellite U500 laptop is powering on each day at 8:50 although BIOS doesn't have any settings for that

Tags: laptop, bios, wake-up, scheduling

Toshiba Satellite U500 laptop is not in sleep state, but is completely turned off and is still powering itself on each day at 8:50 although BIOS doesn't have any settings for sheduled power on.

All the "Wake" settings like "Wake on LAN" etc. are off, except the "Critical battery wakeup" setting. If it is this very setting, then why does it power on at the fixed time?

How could this be true?

How to disable this behaviour?

Is it possible that some external device (WiFi or Bluetooth) is able to wake it up?

The only things I did with it is that I replaced one of two 2GB RAM modules with 4GB. Now it has 6 GB RAM. Then I replaced its HDD with SSD Samsung 870 EVO 2TB cloning the system 1:1. Unfortunately I cannot remember whether it used to wake up before these changes.

Comment: Did you check the task scheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I suspected, it had nothing to do with OS or SSD or RAM.

At first I assumed that my RAM configuration was causing an addressing conflict with the BIOS. I put the original RAM back into the laptop. It didn't help.

Then I loaded the BIOS setup defaults and it worked. The PC no longer turns on every morning.

Analysis and conclusion:

Obviously, there IS a power-on timer block in the BIOS, but its settings are not displayed in setup.

The problem is solved, but another question arose: what triggered this hidden setting during OS migration? Was it Minitool Partition Wizard v10 or Windows 10 that I tried to install to the SSD before cloning Windows 7 on it?